# Redis connection with express session

Tags: javascript, express, session, redis, express-session

I am using redis and express-session for session of user but when i am doing this operation error is coming.

Error: The client is closed
at Commander._RedisClient_sendCommand (/Users/aaryarastogi/MERN_Projects/tourism/backend/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:510:31)
at Commander.commandsExecutor (/Users/aaryarastogi/MERN_Projects/tourism/backend/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:190:154)
at Commander.<computed>.<computed> [as set] (/Users/aaryarastogi/MERN_Projects/tourism/backend/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/commander.js:58:33)
at RedisStackAsyncStore.set (/Users/aaryarastogi/MERN_Projects/tourism/backend/node_modules/connect-redis-stack/dist/index.js:92:28)
at /Users/aaryarastogi/MERN_Projects/tourism/backend/node_modules/connect-redis-stack/dist/index.js:48:32
at RedisStackStore.set (/Users/aaryarastogi/MERN_Projects/tourism/backend/node_modules/connect-redis-stack/dist/index.js:53:7)
at Session.save (/Users/aaryarastogi/MERN_Projects/tourism/backend/node_modules/express-session/session/session.js:72:25)
at Session.save (/Users/aaryarastogi/MERN_Projects/tourism/backend/node_modules/express-session/index.js:406:15)
at ServerResponse.end (/Users/aaryarastogi/MERN_Projects/tourism/backend/node_modules/express-session/index.js:335:21)
at ServerResponse.send (/Users/aaryarastogi/MERN_Projects/tourism/backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:232:10)

Can anyone help me in solving this issue?

Solve my issue and give me updated code or tell me where i am lacking.
Tell me how to connect redis 4th version with express-session using connect-redis 7th version.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.